# react native passing onPress with value

Tags: reactjs, react-native, onpress

I have a parent component that creates a child component that passes an "onPress" to the parent,

Works fine, but now need to pass some value from child to parent...

the parent component:

```
const filterBarTapped = ( index:any )=> {
  console.log('tongo:', index )

}

const Charter = ({ isSingle, isDarkMode, data1, data2 }: Charterprops) => {

  return (
    <View>
      { Object.keys(data1).length > 6 && <TabBar data={data1} onPress={() => filterBarTapped()}/>} ...
```

the child:

```
const handleClick = (index:any) => {
    setSelectedTab(index)
    console.log("sale index:", index)
     onPress()

}

return (
        <View style={{
            flexDirection: "row",
            justifyContent: 'space-around',
            alignItems: 'center',
        }}>


            {tabs.map(p => (

                <Tab
                    title={p.title}
                    onPress={() => handleClick(p.itemIndex)}
                    itemIndex={p.itemIndex}
                    selectedItem={selectedTab} />
            ))}

        </View>
    )
}
```

But I'm getting,

> tongo: undefined

So, how to pass the index to the parent for my onPress?

cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the value to the onPress callback

child

```
onPress(index)
```

then update it in the filter function

```
onPress={(index) => filterBarTapped(index)}
```

In order to be accessible on `filterBarTapped` function

Shortcut:

Since `onPress` and `filterBarTapped` have the same number of args you can just write:

```
onPress={filterBarTapped}
```

on the parent component

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

<del><TabBar data={data1} onPress={() => filterBarTapped()}/>}</del>

You can directly pass the `filterBarTapped` function

```
<TabBar data={data1} onPress={filterBarTapped}/>}
```

In this way, whatever value is passed from `onPresss` event will be available to `filterBarTapped` function. and the code becomes little bit more maintainable.